# use ifstream with a string instead of a file in c++?

Tags: c++

`ifstream` has nice tools for parsing files, such as `<<` which work in loops and can consume floats, ints, or whatever you want into variables (as long as your variable types match what you are trying to consume with `<<`. I want to know if, instead of:

```
ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open(some_file); // open the file
float x;
int y;
// some_file = "0.5 5"
myReadFile >> x >> y;
```

If I can somehow get a string object that is identical to some_file into ifstream. What I want to do is:

```
ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile = my_string
...
```

Essentially parsing files is easy with ifstreams but parsing strings in c++ is a PITA (compared to say, Python).

Comment: `ifstream` stands for Input File stream. `>>` actually works on any kind of input stream, it doesn't "belong" to `ifstream`. Similarly, `>>` works on any `ostream` including `ofstream` (Output to File)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
// Initialize contents of the stream with your string
std::stringstream myReadString(my_string);  

float x;
int y;

// Use the stream just like an fstream
// my_string = "0.5 5"
myReadString >> x >> y;
```

Comment: does this work like ifstream even if there is arbitrary whitespace between x and y?

Comment: @Tommy They're basically have the same functionality as the other stream types (`istream`, `ifstream`...), only that they have different data sources. They should work the same.

Comment: @Tommy: The *only* difference is that `ifstream` may perform newline conversion. In particular, on Windows a newline is CR+LF on disk but `\n` in memory. Since stringstreams are entirely in memory, no translation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

erm, you might want to look at `stringstream`.